# Code A Contract To Accept A Different Token (Other Than ETH)

Tags: contract-design, tokens, erc-20

I'm developing a DApp for Decentraland that will accept payments in their ERC-20 token MANA. How can I code a smart contract to accept a token other than Eth? How can msg.value know the value of a different token?

Also, how can I store MANA in the smart contract (as address(this).balance)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`address(this).balance` and `msg.value` exclusively relate to ether, so you can't get those to somehow show you token amounts.

But to accept tokens, the caller needs to first call `approve(<address>, <amount>)` on the token, where `<address>` is the address of your contract, and `<amount>` is the number of tokens. Then when they call a function on your contract, you can call `token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount)` to transfer the tokens to the contract. You can check the contract's token balance with `token.balanceOf(address(this))`. In those calls, `token` is the contract for the token you want to use.